# UITableview not reloading after UIAlertview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

After entering with a new item, in the delegate method from `UIAlertView`, I call `reloadData` of `UITableview` and it is not being updated:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
                                           forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        if (indexPath.row > 0) 
        {
            [datController RemoveData:indexPath.row-1];
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }

    } 
    else if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
    {
        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter the item." message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];    

        fldItem = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
        [fldItem setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [myAlertView addSubview:fldItem];

        [tableView reloadData]; 
        [myAlertView show];
        [myAlertView release];          
    }       

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    if(buttonIndex == 0){}          
    else 
    {   
        [datController AddData:fldItem.text];
        [self.tableView reloadData];        
    }
}
```

Note that `reloadData` in the method `commitEditingStyle`, I put in for debugging purposes only, and this place it's working.

Method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which redraws the tableview, is not fired after execute `reloadData`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    //Try to get rusable (rusable) cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        //If not possible create a new cell
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0) reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    // Get the string to display and set the value in the cell
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text  = @"Add items...";
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [datController ListData:indexPath.row-1];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what would have gone wrong to end up in the situation, but are you sure that `self.view` is not nil?

In the place the `reloadData` call is working you're using the `tableView` reference passed to you and not `self.view`, but the call that isn't working is using `self.view`.  With just the code above that's the only obvious thing I noticed so far.

Comment: I'm not sure that self.tableview is not nil. Actually, I have doubts about should I call the reloadData from Tableview, in the delegate method cellForRowAtIndexPath. 
Any suggestion? 
Thank you.

Comment: You should absolutely not call `reloadData` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the method clickedButtonAtIndex. How should I call in this method.

Comment: Whether you should or should not call it from clickedButtonAtIndex: is determined by the design of your software, and I can't really say whether it's a good idea or not. I can say that you clearly wrote that method expecting `self.tableView` was not nil, so if it is, you should figure out why.